# There is a non removable, outward protruding speck on my MacBook screen, Apple is denying warranty coverage

Tags: macbook-pro, warranty

A few days ago I noticed a black speck inside my screen, someone suggested it is a thunderfly, others to use a microscope. I took pics using microscope, please help me to classify what the speck is, Apple is denying warranty :(

[image]

Comment: "thunderfly"? What's that?

Comment: Thunderfly is a common name for an insect called a thrip. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrips

Comment: That looks like a chip in the glass from where something impacted it,

Answer (score 3):

Hard to tell without the benefit of 3D vision, but to me that looks like the screen has been punctured from the outside [the small bubbles would seem to confirm it's a puncture].

Bear in mind that anything sharp enough to penetrate through to the actual screen may leave a partially raised 'wound' on the protective layer, which you could mistake for damage coming from within. I'm pretty sure a thunderfly wouldn't be tough enough to be a cause.. they also have legs you'd see under a microscope, even if squished.

Comment: The rgb cells seem fine, they appear warped due to refraction of anti reflection coating and fluid, it is not a puncture , it is outward projecting and the bubble are probably the fluid secreted when the insect squished.

Comment: Then I guess the only way to truly discover what it is is to split the screen out from its protective layer & wipe off the offending whatever-it-is. I don't see us getting any closer from 2D photos at that quality, sorry.

Comment: I have added a new image, kindly inspect.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  There's simply no way an insect could do this type of damage to the *hardened* glass.

Comment: I agree with this answer.  I had a cut or nick on a computer screen just like this a long one ago. If you lightly brushed it with your hand it felt like something was on the monitor.   I can’t imagine a bug doing this

Answer (score 0):

Kindly see the new image, with LCD turned off, the marked regions imo clearly show antennae and legs of an insect.

[image]

Comment: I'm still nowhere near convinced that proves it's an insect, but even if it does you've talked yourself right out of it being covered by warranty & right into needing to claim on your insurance.

Comment: I disagree, the seal was loose hence the insect was able to enter, hence manufacturing defect.

Comment: Well, first you take it to Apple, then you take it to court. I don't see what anyone here can do about it in either case. [If I were you, I'd be in touch with your insurance… far, far simpler]

Comment: That's not an insect.  If it was on the *outside* of the glass, you can easily remove it.  If it was on the inside, the LCD panel would be crushed as the glass is glued to the LCD panel.  Therefore, you would see distortions around the area.  1) It's dam near impossible this would pass Q/A and 2) there's no way an insect would break through the *tempered, scratch resistant glass.*  Something hard with sharp angles impacted the glass and it left a [burr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burr_(edge)).  There's no way it's an insect and there's no way Apple's going to cover it.

Comment: I do not know how it got inside, but its thorax, antennae and pair of legs are clearly visible and I have verified that from zoologists. And if you Google there are many instances of thunderfly getting inside lcd.

Comment: I'm sticking with my last comment. Take it to Apple or take it to court. There's nothing anyone here can do about it, whatever it is.